# SyncFusion JS chart - Tooltips behave wrong

Tags: javascript, html, svg, syncfusion

I'm using SyncFusion for Javascript to render charts in my app. I have a StepChart with several series, continuous X axis and unequal intervals between data points. I want to show a tooltip with description when user hovers certain point. But it doesn't work as expected. **Sometimes tooltips are shown for the wrong points, and for some points they are not shown at all.**

[image: Wrong tooltip]

It seem's there's some clever algorithm that decides what tooltip should be shown for each area... Unfortunately, it doesn't work for me. It would be enough just to **show tooltip when user's mouse is exactly over the dot** (as my dots are quite big).

```js
$(function() {
  $("#container").ejChart({
    primaryXAxis: {
      valueType: 'datetime',
      range: {
        min: new Date(1422874800000),
        max: new Date(1422878400000),
        interval: 5
      },
      intervalType: 'Minutes'
    },
    primaryYAxis: {
      title: {
        text: 'Value'
      },
      range: {
        min: 0,
        max: 300
      }
    },
    commonSeriesOptions: {
      type: 'stepline',
      enableAnimation: true,
      marker: {
        shape: 'circle',
        size: {
          height: 12,
          width: 12
        },
        visible: true
      },
      border: {
        width: 2
      },
      tooltip: {
        visible: true,
        format: "#point.x#<br/>#series.name# value is #point.y# "
      }
    },

    series: [{
      "name": "Line 1",
      "enableAnimation": false,
      "points": [{
        "x": new Date(1422874800000),
        "y": 100
      }, {
        "x": new Date(1422875280000),
        "y": 160
      }, {
        "x": new Date(1422875520000),
        "y": 200
      }, {
        "x": new Date(1422876180000),
        "y": 200
      }]
    }, {
      "name": "Line 2",
      "enableAnimation": false,
      "points": [{
        "x": new Date(1422874800000),
        "y": 50
      }, {
        "x": new Date(1422875400000),
        "y": 170
      }, {
        "x": new Date(1422875880000),
        "y": 180
      }, {
        "x": new Date(1422876180000),
        "y": 180
      }]
    }, {
      "name": "Line 3",
      "enableAnimation": false,
      "points": [{
        "x": new Date(1422874800000),
        "y": 120
      }, {
        "x": new Date(1422874980000),
        "y": 140
      }, {
        "x": new Date(1422875400000),
        "y": 240
      }, {
        "x": new Date(1422875880000),
        "y": 260
      }, {
        "x": new Date(1422876180000),
        "y": 260
      }]
    }],
    canResize: true,
    title: {
      text: 'Step Chart'
    },
    legend: {
      visible: true
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://js.syncfusion.com/demos/web/scripts/jquery.globalize.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://js.syncfusion.com/demos/web/themes/ej.widgets.core.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="http://js.syncfusion.com/demos/web/themes/default.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="http://js.syncfusion.com/demos/web/themes/default-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="http://js.syncfusion.com/demos/web/themes/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="http://js.syncfusion.com/demos/web/themes/default-theme/ej.widgets.all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="http://js.syncfusion.com/demos/web/themes/default-theme/ej.theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="http://js.syncfusion.com/demos/web/scripts/ej.web.all.min.js"></script>
<div class="content-container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cols-sample-area">
      <div id="container"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I've posted the issue on SyncFusion forum. Got a reply: this is actually a bug and it will be fixed in the upcoming release (February 2015).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stated issue is fixed and fix for this is included in 2015, Vol 1 Essential studio release, which is rolled on first week of April, 2015.This can be downloaded from the below link

Link: http://www.syncfusion.com/forums/118723/essential-studio-2015-volume-1-final-release-v13-1-0-21-available-for-download

Let me know if this helps